# HERE API - TMC to Coordinates

Tags: java, gis, geospatial, here-api, here-olp

I've been using the HERE Java library to decode binary TPEG files, however I am running into trouble when trying to get locations from the TMC location reference.

I'd like to be able to take the TMC reference (location id, country code, location table version) and get lat/long coordinates. Unfortunately, after pouring through HERE's API docs, I can't seem to find an API that would do this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a [`TMCLocationReference`](https://developer.here.com/documentation/location-library/api_reference_java/com/here/platform/location/tpeg2/tmc/TMCLocationReference.html), you can transform it to a [`LinearLocation`](https://developer.here.com/documentation/location-library/api_reference_java/com/here/platform/location/referencing/LinearLocation.html) using [`LocationReferenceResolvers.tmc`](https://developer.here.com/documentation/location-library/api_reference_java/content/com/here/platform/location/referencing/javadsl/LocationReferenceResolvers.html) method.

There should be an example in [Resolving a Location Reference](https://developer.here.com/documentation/location-library/dev_guide/docs/location-referencing-tmc.html) section.

The resolver allows you to transform the `TMCLocationReference` into a `LinearLocation` containing internal HERE maps ids, which can be transformed to WKT like [`LineString`s](https://developer.here.com/documentation/location-library/api_reference_java/com/here/platform/location/core/geospatial/javadsl/LineString.html) using for instance the [`PropertyMaps.geometry`](https://developer.here.com/documentation/location-library/api_reference_java/com/here/platform/location/integration/optimizedmap/graph/javadsl/PropertyMaps.html) method, for which you can find more details in the [dev guide](https://developer.here.com/documentation/location-library/dev_guide/docs/high-level.html#property-maps).

As an example, you could do something like this:

```java
StandaloneCatalogFactory scf = new StandaloneCatalogFactory();
Catalog optimizedMap = scf.create(OptimizedMap.v2.HRN);
CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManager.withLruCache();

LocationReferenceResolver<TMCLocationReference, BidirectionalLinearLocation> tmcResolver =
        LocationReferenceResolvers.tmc(optimizedMap, cacheManager);

TMCLocationReference tmcLocationReference = ...
BidirectionalLinearLocation linearLocation = tmcResolver.resolve(tmcLocationReference);
PropertyMap<Vertex, LineStringHolder<GeoCoordinate>> geometry =
        PropertyMaps.geometry(optimizedMap, cacheManager);

LineStringHolder<GeoCoordinate> lineString =
        geometry.get(linearLocation.getLocation().getPath().get(0));
```